# Azure: get-azureSchedulerJob : ResourceNotFound: The cloud service is not valid

Tags: powershell, azure, scheduler

Using powershell 5, I'm trying to manage my scheduler jobs, however ... when I type:

```
get-azureSchedulerJob -Location "West Europe" -JobCollectionName nicejobcollection
```

I get the following error:

```
get-azureSchedulerJob : ResourceNotFound: The cloud service is not valid.
```

Both of the  following commands give proper results:
Get-AzureSubscription
Get-AzureRMSubscription

Any thoughts?

UPDATE: Running Get-AzureRmResource does show the resource nicejobcollection

```
Name              : NiceJobCollection
ResourceId        : /subscriptions/<subscriptionGuid>/resourceGroups/RGName-Europe/providers
                    /Microsoft.Scheduler/jobcollections/NiceJobCollection
ResourceName      : NiceJobCollection
ResourceType      : Microsoft.Scheduler/jobcollections
ResourceGroupName : RGName-Europe
Location          : westeurope
SubscriptionId    : <subscriptionGuid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited 04/15/2016 to reflect to the latest resolution**

It appears all powershell command related to scheduler jobs so far are only polling results from a default resource group created by old azure portal or created directly from powershell command: `New-AzureSchedulerJobCollection -JobCollectionName *** -Location *** -Plan ***`

The default group name would appear as resource gourp `cs-*LOCATION*-scheduler` in new portal

However, when creating a schedulerjob collection in new portal, you will be asked to select a resource group, which would not be recognized by powershell later on, and queries would fail.

I attempted to target the customized resource group in powershell but don't have much luck. I know there was a way to target a storage account by `Set-AzureSubscription -CurrentStorageAccountName` but couldn't find anything similar for resource group.

Thus, the resolution so far is having all schedulerjobs handled by old portal, so they can be accessed by powershell.

Comment: This I dont quiet understand. When I log into portal.azure.com I use my microsoft account. I clearly can see the subscription. The scheduler has this same subscription. I've used select-azuresubscription  -subscriptionid <id> -> that gives me no response, simply the prompt on the next line.  Running Get-AzureSchedulerJob .. gives same result.   When I try this with Select-AzureRMSubscription ... it provides feedback which seems good. But then running Get-AzureSchedulerJob again, gives same error still.

Comment: If you run `Get-AzureSchedulerJobCollection`, does it show the desired collection in the list, or does it show anything at all? I'm getting close but don't see the full picture yet. Seems powershell is having problem to show scheduler job created in new portal. I think the root cause is the resource group tagged is not recognized, or not properly selected by powrshell but don't have hard evidence. If you create a schedulerjob in powrshell `New-AzureSchedulerJobCollection -JobCollectionName "test_collection" -Location "West Europe" -Plan "Free"` you should be able see it.

Comment: Thanks for the input ;-) Get-AzureSchedulerJobCollection does return without error nor message ...

Comment: The New-AzureSchedulerJobCollection cmd returns New-AzureSchedulerJobCollection : InternalError : The server encountered an internal error. Please retry the request.

Comment: I retried: second attempt, different response: New-AzureSchedulerJobCollection : A job collection with name "test_collection" already exists in West Europe. Please
specify a different name.

Comment: I retried at this point: Get-AzureSchedulerJobCollection -> response: Get-AzureSchedulerJobCollection : NotFound: Cannot find job collection 'test_collection' under subscription
'<subscriptionGuid>' and container 'cs-WestEurope-scheduler'.

Comment: Yep, if you login to manage.windowsazure.com, go after scheduler, it will tell you the reason it cannot be created is you can only have one free tier in your subscription. You can delete the newly created one, the error would go away. You can either re-create a standard one (costs), or you can remove the free one you already have and re-try. The outcome matches what I have, the schedulerjob is tagged with 'cs-WestEurope-scheduler', this would show as a resource gourp property in new portal, and seems this is the only place the powershell command would poll from.

Comment: you are right. Only 1 free job allowed. I removed the free jobs, and the errors .. and retried adding with the new-AzureSchedulerJobCollection ... it worked! I can now see in the portal new jobcollection. (FYI: The errors did show up in the old portal, but not in the new portal).

Comment: Get-AzureSchedulerJobCollection now responds with the newly created JobCollection. But it is not showing the 'existing JobCollections' which I have in my Azure account

Comment: It appears that the issue boils down to the fact that the resource group that I created in the new Azure Portal does not show up in the PowerShell interface ... They do show up in the old portal. The newly created job collections and jobs (created using the powershell command) show up everywhere (in the old portal, the new portal and in the powershell commands). Apparently the New-AzureSchedulerJobCollection created a resource group which is somehow connected differently?? That raises new questiosn, but for this issue ... it is closed. Thanks a million Kai!!

Comment: This is where I stuck. If you go to portal.azure.com, schedulerjob, click on any collections you already have. Under the 'Essentials', first thing is 'Resource group'. It appears to me powershell would only poll from 'cs-location-scheduler' resource groups, which are generated automatically from old portal or powershell, nothing else. I'm trying to see if I can declare a customized resource group selection somewhere in powershell.